# Set Target Kong with Domain in HOST

Tags: lua, kong, kong-plugin, nginx-upstreams, upstream

I developed a new plugin that basically receives a call and directs it, according to some criteria, to a configured target.

To accomplish this targeting, I'm using

> kong.service.set_target("server.server", 80)

With that I get an error similar to this:

> [error] 45212#0: *310 [lua] init.lua:1168: balancer(): failed to set the current peer (address: http://server.server port: 80): invalid host while connecting to upstream, client: 00.000.00.00

The Host is directly accessible from the machine where KONG is. I tried to add the following configuration: **dns_resolver** but without success too and the **resolv.conf** file has the correct settings

From my research, the error occurs at this moment:

> init.lua[1166] - set_current_peer(balancer_data_ip, balancer_data_port, pool_opts)

From what I understand, this method does not support to be used with a domain...

Is there any way out for this? Unfortunately I need to use the domain for this upstream.

Is there any way to **upstream** using **set_target** to a domain in Kong?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't use  `http://server.server` instead of `server.server` ?